# Как добавить option в начало select с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, select, html-form, html-select

Это добавляет новый option в конец select.
Есть ли какой-нибудь способ добавить новый option в начало, не перебирая весь список option циклом?

```
let select = document.getElementById('slideNumber');
let optoins = select.optoins;
let newOption = new Option('1', '1');
select.append(newOption);
```

Comment: **ВНИМАНИЕ** нет такой свойства как `optoins`, существует `options`, стоит заменить, если вы не хотите ошибок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `.prepend`.

```js
let select = document.getElementById('slideNumber');
let optoins = select.optoins;
let newOption = new Option('1', '1');
select.prepend(newOption);
```

```html
<select id="slideNumber">
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```